# Excel Specific Average: Every X and then Y lines

Tags: excel, average, rows

I have some data, chemical samples in fact, listed according to a numbering scheme. I need to make averages of analysis results in Excel, but every X and Y rows.

Example Sheet

[image]

On the example sheet picture attached, I need to average every row with sample ID finishing with 1,2 and 3, then average over sample ID rows 4 and 5, and then again. And then drag down for all data.
This is like averaging every 3 rows, then every 2 rows, then every 3 rows, then every 2 rows, etc.

I would highly appreciate any help to this quite difficult problem!

Many thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what output you're looking for, so here's a picture with the formula I'd use and sample data/output.

For copy paste:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="1", AVERAGE(B2:B4), IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="4", AVERAGE(B2:B3), ""))
```

This just checks if the ID ends in a 1 or a 4, then averages either 2 or 3 values based on that. If it's neither, then it leaves the value blank. It should be draggable to the whole column without any issues.

Tell me if that's not what you're looking for, but I imagine something along these lines will work.

[image: Like this?]